# android-pdf-viewer-library could not load pdf files

Tags: android, pdf

I have used **android-pdf-viewer-library** to show pdf files in a pdf viewer. But I have used following method and pdfViewer class to do that. But my problem is when the pdfViewer open, a dialog will be appeared "Loading pdf pages" for long time and nothing can be viewed. Can anyone tell what is the problem?

```
import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PdfViewer extends PdfViewerActivity{

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
     return R.drawable.left_arrow;
    }

    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
     return R.drawable.right_arrow;
    }

    public int getZoomInImageResource() {
     return R.drawable.zoom_in;
    }

    public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
     return R.drawable.zoom_out;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
     return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
     return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
     return R.id.etPassword;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
     return R.id.btOK;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
     return R.id.btExit;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
     return R.id.pagenum_edit;
    }
}
```

**in openPdf method:**

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Books/"+filename );
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainContainer.this, PdfViewer.class);
    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, file);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

N.B.: The pdfPath (file) is ok